# Having Issue On Pushing Array Into Two Dimension Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know why the `storage.push(players)` instead of adding new array/set of `players` into `storage` is merging them with previously added array?

Technically what I am expecting here is getting something like this

```
[
  [2,52,35,16,18,46],
  [18,44,66,25,78,26]
]
```

but what I am getting now is only one array in storage like

```
[
  [2,52,35,16,18,46,18,44,66,25,78,26]
]
```

```js
var storage = [];
var players = [];


function createplayers(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let a = true,
      n;
    while (a) {
      n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      a = arr.includes(n);
    }
    arr.push(n);
  }
}

var x = 3;
var interval = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    createplayers(players);
    storage.push(players)
    console.log(players)
    console.log(storage)
  }, i * interval)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you look in the browser console, you *are* getting 3 arrays in your final `storage`.   They all have the same values, but it's not a single array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your had only one `players` array all the time. Move the array creation to `createplayers()`.

```js
var storage = [];


function createplayers() {
  var arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let a = true,
      n;
    while (a) {
      n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      a = arr.includes(n);
    }
    arr.push(n);
  }
  return arr;
}

var x = 3;
var interval = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var players = createplayers();
    storage.push(players)
    console.log(players)
    console.log(storage)
  }, i * interval)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @freedomn-m without your modification it actually produces an array of 3 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This Question has nothing to do with `jQuery`

You have to clear the players array everytime you add to storage.
Here is the solution

```
var storage = [];
var players = [];


function createplayers(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let a = true,
      n;
    while (a) {
      n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      a = arr.includes(n);
    }
    arr.push(n);
  }
}

var x = 3;
var interval = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    createplayers(players);
    storage.push(players)
    console.log(players)

    //Notice this line
    players=[];
    console.log(storage)
  }, i * interval)
}
```